# Strech an Image out of the Grid

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and i have an image which i want to strech out side the box. as shown below.

[image]

What i have got

[image]

Link: http://goo.gl/zn7zI

How can i stretch the image across the full width ? so that at all screen sizes it will give the same effect.

Comment: Is the image inside a Bootstrap `container`, `row` or `span` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.features-story
{
width: 270px;
}
.features-story .featured-title {
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0;
padding-right: 41px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is achieved from `<div class="box">`

make its padding to be 0px I mean right and left padding!